# AssetManager.exists(String) equivalent?

Tags: android, assets

My understanding is it is better practice to test beforehand to avoid exceptions, rather than catching them. Is there any way to check if an asset file exists before attempting to open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature available to assets, however, there is no need for it (see below).

> My understanding is it is better practice to test beforehand to avoid exceptions, rather than catching them.

This is only true if an exception is a part of the normal (expected) operation of your application. In other words, if an exception is a statistically common event (e.g. you expect it to happen "often" at a certain place), then catching it may have significant performance costs. (In practice, this matters only in case of many exceptions caught in a short period of time, so benchmarking is always important.)

Since you usually don't expect an asset to be missing when trying to access it (otherwise something is wrongly designed in your application), it is fine to use an exception handler for exceptional cases.

To sum up, error handling with exceptions has performance costs, but errors (especially errors to be suppressed) are expected to be rare events. If you expect errors to happen very often in a certain part of your application, then something may be wrong in your design. (Some very exceptional situations are possible where this is not true, but these are very rare and atypical application domains.)

**In practice:** in your case, e.g. it is OK to use exceptions if the asset name comes from external (e.g. user) input. This is because the "frequency" of possible exceptions is low. On the other hand, if you are trying to decide for many assets if each of them exists (e.g. in a loop), then exception handling might have unacceptable performance costs -- but I can hardly imagine that such a thing would be needed.

Comment: In the case of my app it actually is in a loop, but it is not a hard hit on performance. What is happening is that I have a soundboard, and it has a very large volume of sounds (over 100). Each sound is presented with its file name (minus the .ogg) and the sounds are split up into folders which are "categories". There is a spinner in the app in which a player can choose a category and the the sound list is populated based on the files in that folder. The exception handling comes in on the 'favorites' list.

Comment: The user can add sounds to this list. The list is saved and later when they choose the favorites category it is populated. Since I only have the filename minus the .ogg when it comes time to play a sound in the favorites folder I must search or it. I get a list of directories and try each directory until I find the file. Saving the folder name with the sound in the favorites list is not an option as the button formatting looks terrible when the folder is included. I considered having a custom button and listener for the list, but that seems a rather long winded implementation.

Comment: I suppose what I'll do is get a new list from each directory and make sure the file name is present in that directory and use the file if it is instead of catching exceptions, but still a exists function would have made a more readable implementation.

Comment: What about using an auxiliary structure for maintaining information on the files (including the favorites)? For example, when the user adds a filename to his or her favorites, then you could store the exact data (i.e. where exactly the file is located) somewhere (and persist it to stable storage). Then when you need to repopulate the favorites list again, you can access this extended structure (instead of just iterating over plain filenames). This is the correct design in case of this application, and it needs exception handling only in actual error situations.

Comment: I will switch to the method you suggested. Thanks for the help